# How to use PostgreSQLEnumType with Hibernate 6.3

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am using spring boot v3.2.0 and hibernate v6.3.1

And tring to use JdbcType annotation for my enum field:

```java
enum STATUS {
    DRAFT, NEW, IN_PROGRESS, COMPLETED, REJECTED;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
@JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType.class)
private STATUS status;
```

Next, I wrote a method in my Repository interface with native query as follows:

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM requests r WHERE r.status IN (?1)")
List<Request> getRequestsByStatus(List<Request.STATUS> statuses);
```

*I used `nativeQuery = true` option because my actual query is more complex and I find it easier to use a native query to fetch the data. So here this option is just to reproduce the problem.*

When I call the `getRequestsByStatus` method, I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT * FROM requests r WHERE r.status IN (?,?,?,?,?)] [ERROR: operator does not exist: request_statuses = smallint
```

Oh, yeah. In the database, the `status` column also has the ENUM type (request_statuses). But it doesn't matter here, as I think.

Digging a bit into the Hibernate code, I found the following:

[link to source L149](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/1c5bdd51514c5b72195be7187d185f5406f65e24/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/sql/exec/internal/AbstractJdbcParameter.java#L149)

```java
    private static <E extends Enum<E>> BasicTypeImpl<E> createEnumType(ExecutionContext executionContext, Class<E> enumClass) {
        final EnumJavaType<E> enumJavaType = new EnumJavaType<>( enumClass );
        final JdbcTypeIndicators indicators =
                executionContext.getSession().getTypeConfiguration().getCurrentBaseSqlTypeIndicators();
        final JdbcType jdbcType =
                // we don't know whether to map the enum as ORDINAL or STRING,
                // so just accept the default from the TypeConfiguration, which
                // is usually ORDINAL (the default according to JPA)
                enumJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(indicators);
        return new BasicTypeImpl<>( enumJavaType, jdbcType );
    }
```

+ [link to source getRecommendedJdbcType method](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/1c5bdd51514c5b72195be7187d185f5406f65e24/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/EnumJavaType.java#L39) where implemented switch by ORDINAL and STRING types for JdbcType.

As I understand it, the problem is to specify JdbcType as STRING instead of ORDINAL, but I don't know how to do that.

I tried editing my query by making the left and right sides to VARCHAR:

```sql
AND cast(r.status AS VARCHAR) = ANY(cast(ARRAY[?1] AS VARCHAR[]))
```

It almost works! Despite the fact that the parameter values are still populated as ORDINAL in the final query, I get the expected result...... but with only one parameter :(
That is, if I pass multiple ENUM values, hibernate will glue all the values into one string and the query will return nothing.

The last thing I did was explicitly convert the list of enum to a list of strings:

```java
List<Request.STATUS> ers = Arrays.asList( Request.STATUS.COMPLETED, Request.STATUS.REJECTED );

List<String> statuses = new ArrayList<>(ers.size());
ers.forEach( s-> statuses.add( s.name()));
```

And change my query:

```sql
AND cast(r.status AS VARCHAR) = IN (?1)
```

Okay, it works. But it looks like a crutch. I would like to have full support for java enums in queries.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Unfortunately, I am facing the exact same issue :(